# Soft 404 Errors in Google Search Console for Angular Web App with Universal SSR

Tags: angular, seo, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, google-search-console

In my current project, I'm using Angular Universal for server-side rendering (SSR) in an Angular web application. For several of our dynamically created sites, such as specific product pages (for example, /products/t-shirt-20), we have been experiencing soft 404 errors in Google Search Console.

For some pages, we were able to fix the problem by not only showing an error page, but also returning a 404 error code when the site could not be reached. However, numerous pages with dynamic content continue to give us soft 404 errors.

All of the pages are being crawled by the Googlebot, but some of them are not being correctly indexed. I'm looking for suggestions on how to resolve this problem for the remaining pages, as well as any best practices to avoid soft 404 errors in the future.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: read more https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/06/crawl-errors-now-reports-soft-404s

Comment: Did you ever rectify this? I have a similar issue on my blogs section. You could ensure the website returns a 404 status using a Cloud Function, instead of the Angular 200 it may receive? Ensure you remove and then add canonical tags for each dynamic page?